# make_pipeline()f TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am trying to make a stacked classifier that uses count vectorization, gradient boosting and then Naive baised. However, I get a type error for my make_pipeline function.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier

estimators = [make_pipeline(('vec', CountVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words= 'english', ngram_range=(1,2))),
                            ('gbc', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate = 0.25, max_features = 'sqrt', n_estimators = 500)))]


clf = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=MultinomialNB(alpha=0.1))
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

This is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10224/3708809530.py in <module>
      7 estimators = [
      8                 ('gbc', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate = 0.25, max_features = 'sqrt', n_estimators = 500)),
----> 9                 make_pipeline('vec', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = 'english', ngram_range = (1, 2)),
     10                 ('gbc', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate = 0.25, max_features = 'sqrt', n_estimators = 500)))]
     11 

~\anaconda3\envs\comp4331\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in make_pipeline(memory, verbose, *steps)
    868                     ('gaussiannb', GaussianNB())])
    869     """
--> 870     return Pipeline(_name_estimators(steps), memory=memory, verbose=verbose)
    871 
    872 

~\anaconda3\envs\comp4331\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in __init__(self, steps, memory, verbose)
    146         self.memory = memory
    147         self.verbose = verbose
--> 148         self._validate_steps()
    149 
    150     def get_params(self, deep=True):

~\anaconda3\envs\comp4331\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _validate_steps(self)
    205                 t, "transform"
    206             ):
--> 207                 raise TypeError(
    208                     "All intermediate steps should be "
    209                     "transformers and implement fit and transform "

TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'vec' (type <class 'str'>) doesn't
```

Answer (score 0):

`make_pipeline` does not accept names for its steps, and the steps need to be provided as a tuple.  Either:

```py
estimators = [make_pipeline((
    CountVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words= 'english', ngram_range=(1,2)),
    GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate = 0.25, max_features = 'sqrt', n_estimators = 500),
))]
```

(in which case the names of the steps will be `"countvectorizer"` and `"gradientboostingclassifier"`)

or

```py
estimators = [Pipeline([
    ('vec', CountVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1,2))),
    ('gbc', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.25, max_features='sqrt', n_estimators=500)),
])]
```